I couldn't start airflow dag with python
Everything seems fine but I don't know why Airflow didn't work My mistake is in this image

I did download airflow from official airflow website, at the same time download docker. I tryied that run the kafka in the airflow but did not
Finally I decided this code. There are did not see each other my python code and dag code
DataGenerator and kafka producer code
import random
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time
from kafka import KafkaProducer

btype = ['TL', 'USD', 'EURO']
banks = [f'{chr(i)}_Bank' for i in range(65, 65 + 15)]  # A'dan başlayarak 15 banka
cities = ["Adana", "Adıyaman", "Afyonkarahisar", "Ağrı", "Aksaray", "Amasya", "Ankara", "Antalya", "Ardahan", "Artvin",
           "Aydın", "Balıkesir", "Bartın", "Batman", "Bayburt", "Bilecik", "Bingöl", "Bitlis", "Bolu", "Burdur",
           "Bursa", "Çanakkale", "Çankırı", "Çorum", "Denizli", "Diyarbakır", "Düzce", "Edirne", "Elazığ", "Erzincan",
           "Erzurum", "Eskişehir", "Gaziantep", "Giresun", "Gümüşhane", "Hakkari", "Hatay", "Iğdır", "Isparta", "İstanbul",
           "İzmir", "Kahramanmaraş", "Karabük", "Karaman", "Kars", "Kastamonu", "Kayseri", "Kırıkkale", "Kırklareli", "Kırşehir",
           "Kilis", "Kocaeli", "Konya", "Kütahya", "Malatya", "Manisa", "Mardin", "Mersin", "Muğla", "Muş", "Nevşehir",
           "Niğde", "Ordu", "Osmaniye", "Rize", "Sakarya", "Samsun", "Şanlıurfa", "Siirt", "Sinop", "Şırnak",
           "Sivas", "Tekirdağ", "Tokat", "Trabzon", "Tunceli", "Uşak", "Van", "Yalova", "Yozgat", "Zonguldak"]

def read_file():
    with open("isimler.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        name_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    with open("soyisimler.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        surname_list = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

    return name_list, surname_list

def generate_oid():
    return random.randint(10000000000, 99999999999)

def generate_iban():
    return 'TR' + ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(24)])

def generate_name(name_list, surname_list):
    name = random.choice(name_list)
    surname = random.choice(surname_list)
    return f"{name} {surname}"

def generate_city():
    return random.choice(cities)

def create_dict(name_list, surname_list):
    sender_info = {
        'bank': random.choice(banks),
        'iban': generate_iban(),
        'name': generate_name(name_list, surname_list),
        'city': generate_city()
    }

    receiver_info = {
        'bank': random.choice(banks),
        'iban': generate_iban(),
        'name': generate_name(name_list, surname_list),
        'city': generate_city()
    }

    temp_dict = {
        'pid': generate_oid(),
        'ptype': 'H',
        'sender': sender_info,
        'receiver': receiver_info,
        'balance': random.randint(0, 10000),
        'btype': random.choice(btype),
        'timestamp': str(datetime.now())
    }

    return temp_dict

def create_kafka_producer(bootstrap_servers=None):
    if bootstrap_servers is None:
        bootstrap_servers = ['kafka1:19092', 'kafka2:19093', 'kafka3:19094']
    return KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)

def start_streaming(duration=120):
    producer = create_kafka_producer()
    name_list, surname_list = read_file()
    end_time = time.time() + duration
    
    while True:
        if time.time() > end_time:
            break

        kafka_data = create_dict(name_list, surname_list)
        producer.send("financial_transactions", json.dumps(kafka_data).encode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_streaming()


Mydag code;
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
from data_generator import start_streaming

start_date = datetime.now()

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': start_date,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5)
}

with DAG('financial_transactions_generator', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(seconds=3), catchup=False) as dag:
    data_stream_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='kafka_data_stream',
        python_callable=start_streaming,
        op_args=[120],  # Verilerin 120 saniye boyunca üretilmesini sağlar
        dag=dag,
    )
    data_stream_task


my docker compose.yaml file;
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.8.1/docker-compose.yaml

Could you provide more info. Like tree of files, where are jobs, if it works with other alike imports
